# How do i get the href links when they are invisible from a website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get href links from this website :
https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search
The problem is there are no visible href links even when i inspect the page.

If i use the manual method 'copy link', the link gets copied.

How is that possible?

```
import re
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15"
]

driver_path = '/users/tosh/downloads/chromedriver'
user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

inactive_tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Inactive__item"]')
inactive_tab.click()
time.sleep(5)

link_list = []
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.slds-text-heading_small lgorg')
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    link_list.append(href)

print(link_list)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  If there are no links then... there are no links.  What links are you trying to scrape and why do you expect them to be there?  Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: if i manually use 'copy link',  there is a link.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually use 'copy link'"?  Please don't rely on us to examine and debug the page to which you've linked or assume we know what you're referring to.  Instead, take some time to demonstrate and explain the problem you've encountered here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The problem is there are no visible href links even when i inspect the page.***

Your above statement is the reason why you are not able to scrape the `href`, simple.

Having said that, there is a (not so straight forward) solution to get all the URLs.

**Explanation:** Since there is no `href` attribute in the anchor tag(`<a>`), obviously you cannot use `get_attribute('href')`.

To capture the URLs of the link, the code below will click on each link in a loop and capture the URL using `driver.current_url` method.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search')

# click on Inactive tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Inactive__item']"))).click()
time.sleep(5)

link_list = []
links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//lightning-tab[@id='tab-2']//a[@class='slds-text-heading_small lgorg']")

count = 1
for link in links:
    countStr = str(count)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//lightning-tab[@id='tab-2']//a[@class='slds-text-heading_small lgorg'])[" +countStr+ "]"))).click()
    url = driver.current_url
    link_list.append(url)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Data Privacy Framework List']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Inactive__item']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    count = count +1

print(link_list)
driver.quit()
```

**Console result:**

```
['https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000PFClAAO&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000PJNjAAO&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt00000008WQ8AAM&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000GpEPAA0&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt00000008hXZAAY&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt00000008VqiAAE&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt00000008UzDAAU&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000TOKjAAO&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000eF01AAE&status=Inactive', 'https://www.dataprivacyframework.gov/s/participant-search/participant-detail?id=a2zt0000000PFpOAAW&status=Inactive']

Process finished with exit code 0
```